# Find the point on the paraboloid $z = \frac{x^2}{4}+ \frac{y^2}{25}$ that is closest to the point $(3, 0, 0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the point on the paraboloid $z = \frac{x^2}{4}+ \frac{y^2}{25}$
that is closest to the point $(3, 0, 0)$

Hi all, could someone give me a hint on how to start doing the above question?

Comment: Try minimizing $(\frac {x^2}{4} +\frac {y^2}{25} -3)^2 +x^2 +y^2$ by taking partial derivative with respect to x and y.You will get two equations,solve those for x and y,then find value of z.

Comment: Hi Akshay, how did you get $(\frac {x^2}{4} +\frac {y^2}{25} -3)^2 +x^2 +y^2$?

Comment: By using distance formula

Comment: i think u meant $(\frac {x^2}{4} +\frac {y^2}{25} )^2 +(x-3)^2 +y^2$ ?

Comment: Sorry,I made a mistake in reading.

Answer (score 1):

Set $P=(3,0,0)$.

The function of interest:

$$f(x,y)=\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y}{5}\right)^2$$

Its graph is given by:

$$\phi (u,v)=(u,v,f(u,v))$$

We calculate the normal-vector as follows:

$$\frac{\partial \phi }{\partial u}\times \frac{\partial \phi }{\partial v}(u,v)=\left(-\frac{u}{2},-\frac{1}{25} (2 v),1\right)$$

The normal-vector is perpendicular on the surface.

We now consider the straight-line:

$$\phi (u,v)+t \left(-\frac{u}{2},-\frac{1}{25} (2 v),1\right)$$

and ask, were this line meets P. We are going to solve

$$\phi (u,v)+t \left(-\frac{u}{2},-\frac{1}{25} (2 v),1\right)=P$$
We found these values:

$$u=2,v=0,t=-1$$

There exits other values too, but they are no reals.
Because of

$$\phi (2,0)-P=(-1,0,1)$$

this shortest distance is $\sqrt{2}$.

Have a look what we've done:

[image]

Red line for x-Axis, blue line? Our shortest one.

Were they meet is point P.